# Equidistant nodes with above right =

Tags: positioning, tikz-styles

I'm trying to draw a decision tree. Since the tree branches out to the right, I need to decrease the vertical distance between nodes as I go to the right. However, I want to keep the horizontal distance constant.

I'm aware of the following position possibilities:

- `above right = of nodeA`: Will keep vertical distance constant, can't use this more to the right
- `above right = 0.5cm of nodeA`: Allows me to reduce vertical distance, but will equally shrink horizontal distance
- `above right = 0.5cm and 1cm of nodeA`: Allows me to reduce vertical distance, and control horizontal distance.

Of all these possibilities, the last one seems best. However, I still need to control the `1cm` for all of the different branches - I would rather have all the nodes to space out equidistantly without having to pick a distance that fits the node exactly onto the page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, 
text width=3em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [block] (A) [] {A};
    \node [block] [above right = of A] (B1) {B1};
    \node [block] [below right = of A] (B2) {B2};

    \node [block] [above right = 0.1cm and 1cm of B1] (C1) {C1};
    \node [block] [below right = 0.1cm and 1cm of B1] (C2) {C2};

    \node [block] [above right = 0.1cm and 1cm of B2] (C3) {C3};
    \node [block] [below right = 0.1cm and 1cm of B2] (C4) {C4};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is using `forest` an option? I'm certainly not an expert, but I think it is quite popular for making trees.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, 
text width=3em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=east, block}
[A
  [B1
    [C1] [C2]
  ]
  [B2
    [C3] [C4]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of the [Torbjørn T. answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501508/equidistant-nodes-with-above-right/501533#501533):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {
    draw, rounded corners, minimum size=3em, % nodes style
    grow=0
            }
[A
  [B1
    [C1] 
    [C2]
  ]
  [B2
    [C3] 
    [C4]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the result is the same as at  [Torbjørn T. answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501508/equidistant-nodes-with-above-right/501533#501533).

in case that you like to have only nodes with desired distances bewtween them, then may the following use of `˙forest` be helpful:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {
    draw, rounded corners, minimum size=3em, % nodes style
    grow=0,
    no edge,                                 % n edges between nodes
    s sep=1mm,                               % (vertical/sibling) separation between nodes
    l sep=10mm,                              % (horizontal/level separation between nodes
            }
[A
  [B1
    [C1] 
    [C2]
  ]
  [B2
    [C3] 
    [C4]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added the `node distance` option in block style definition with values are `0.5cm and 1cm`. In my code, `block2` is mine block while `block1` is yours.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
block1/.style = {rectangle, draw, 
text width=3em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em},
block2/.style = {rectangle, draw, 
text width=3em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em,node distance=0.5cm and 1cm}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [block1] (A) [] {A};
    \node [block1] [above right = of A] (B1) {B1};
    \node [block1] [below right = of A] (B2) {B2};

    \node [block1] [above right = 0.1cm and 1cm of B1] (C1) {C1};
    \node [block1] [below right = 0.1cm and 1cm of B1] (C2) {C2};

    \node [block1] [above right = 0.1cm and 1cm of B2] (C3) {C3};
    \node [block1] [below right = 0.1cm and 1cm of B2] (C4) {C4};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}

     \begin{frame}   
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [block2] (A) [] {A};
    \node [block2] [above right = of A] (B1) {B1};
    \node [block2] [below right = of A] (B2) {B2};

    \node [block2] [above right = -0.5cm and 1cm of B1] (C1) {C1};
    \node [block2] [below right = -0.5cm and 1cm of B1] (C2) {C2};

    \node [block2] [above right = -0.5cm and 1cm of B2] (C3) {C3};
    \node [block2] [below right = -0.5cm and 1cm of B2] (C4) {C4};

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's useful, thanks. But you're still manually controlling horizontal distance in every single node, which means that they don't optimally use the space and spread horizontally..